# SSLHandshakeException when i try to send a get or post https request from my webapp in tomcat server

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Follwing exception is thrown when send https request from my webapp in tomcat server

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

here is my servelet

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package LBS;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
//import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.cert.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Ruwan
 */
public class LBS2 extends HttpServlet {

/** 
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        LBS2 s=new LBS2();
        s.myReq();

    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}



public void myReq(){
  System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "10.48.242.90");
  System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3128");
        String uri = "https://somthing.com/abc?username=USERNAME&password=PASWORD";

    try{
        SSLContext sslctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslctx.init(null, new X509TrustManager[] { new MyTrustManager()}, null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslctx.getSocketFactory());
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();
        if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }
        con.disconnect();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
}


    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the +     sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/** 
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}


class MyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String
            authType) {
            }

        @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String
            authType) {
            }

        @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
 }
```

Please help me to find the problem with SSL Certificat handling in this code
thnks in advance

Comment: Did you try this [No more 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'](http://code.naishe.in/2011/07/looks-like-article-no-more-unable-to.html) ?

Comment: NO i didn't, I'll try it out. thanks @Nishant . also could any one please tell me the wrong with above code when run. It is perfectly work in a normal java program run in JVM but not in tomcat server as a webapp

Comment: hmm... that's weird. Ideally, if you are connecting to the same (https) URL, you should see this exception in both -- standalone app, and webapp. I have added the relevant part as an answer to explain as 'how this happens'. But I am unsure why it will depend on container that executes this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this might help: (excerpts from http://code.naishe.in/2011/07/looks-like-article-no-more-unable-to.html )

> Some of you may be familiar with the (not very user friendly) exception message
>
> ```
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> ```
>
> when trying to open an SSL connection to a host using JSSE. What this usually means is that the server is using a test certificate (possibly generated using keytool) rather than a certificate from a well known commercial Certification Authority such as Verisign or GoDaddy. Web browsers display warning dialogs in this case, but since JSSE cannot assume an interactive user is present it just throws an exception by default.

PS: to long for a comment so added as an answer.

Comment: this worked, thank you @Nishant. [this might usefull for some one facing the same problem.](http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes)
just configure tomcat for SSL. thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Your truststore does not trust the server's certificate. You need to export it from the server and install it at the client. The link others have posted shows a way to do that. The real problem is probably that the server is using a self-signed certificate instead of a CA-signed certificate, which just causes this problem for every client. Best solution is to spend the money and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** Normal Java Program worked properly
          But webapp in tomcat server not worked properly although I used the same method/code

**Solution:** 
So I configured the tomcat for SSL Certificate.
If any one having the same problem.
Just configure the tomcat for SSL Certificate.

[This will be helpful to configure tomcat for SSL Certificate](http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes)

Thank you for all the answers and comments. :)

Comment: The truststore you configure at the connector level has nothing to do with the truststore used by your webapps when they're running (unless you're not configuring anything and using the default).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a valid signed wildcard certificate from symantec.

First try running your java application with ***-Djavax.net.debug=SSL*** to see what is really going on.

I ended up ***importing the intermediate certificate*** which was causing the cert chain to break.

I downloaded the missing intermediate cert from symantec (you can see the download link to the missing cert in the ssl handshake log: http://svrintl-g3-aia.verisign.com/SVRIntlG3.cer in my case).

And I imported the cert in the java keystore. After importing the intermediate certificate my wildcard ssl cert finally started working:

```
keytool -import -keystore ../jre/lib/security/cacerts -trustcacerts -alias "VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3" -file /pathto/SVRIntlG3.cer
```

Answer (score -2):

you need return null to bypass  Certificate validation

```
    @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, still same exception thrown:(

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: 1. It is not correct to say that returning null from this method will 'bypass certificate validation'. 2. It is not correct to return `null` at all from this method: see the Javadoc; it is a violation of its contract. 3. It is not correct to write a `TrustManager` that trusts anything, as it violates the entire purpose of the certificate exchange and makes SSL vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. -1.